# Cannot connect to the iTunes store error while modifying subscription

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am testing managing auto-renewable subscriptions inside my app. First, I purchased a subscription then I wanted to modify it. While I am upgrading/downgrading my subscription, I am getting an error

> "Cannot connect to the iTunes store"

I am using sandbox environment and using same sandbox Apple ID because I want to modify same user's subscription. Is this issue related to sandbox environment because I did not get this error for the first purchase?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case this helps anyone else in the future, I received this “Cannot connect” message and it took me a while to track it down.

In my case, I was doing a final run-through of a submission to the app store, testing the flow that Apple was possibly going to be going through during the app review process, and the “manage subscriptions” produced this error. This happened to me because the TestFlight build was using the StoreKit “sandbox” environment, and I didn’t have any subscriptions in that environment. As soon as I added one, the “manage subscriptions” UI worked fine.

So, bottom line, if you don't have any subscriptions in the relevant StoreKit environment, “manage subscriptions” will present a “Cannot connect” message (rather than something more meaningful).